Swagger's @Schema annotations not processed by micronaut-openapi for a file in a different module
In a Micronaut project, I have this endpoint defined in a controller:
@Get
public ClassInDifferentModule getData() {
    return new ClassInDifferentModule();
}

The response class (which is in a different module than the controller class) is defined as:
public static class ClassInDifferentModule {
    @Schema(example = "A")
    private String foo;
    
    ... getters and setters
}

In build.gradle, I have
...
dependencies {
  annotationProcessor("io.micronaut.openapi:micronaut-openapi")
  ...

In the generated openapi specification there is
...
components:
  schemas:
    ClassInDifferentModule:
      type: object
      properties:
        foo:
          type: string
...

but the example for field foo is missing.
So the annotation processor is able to find classes outside current module, but it can't processes their annotations? I can copy-paste the response class to the same module and add a constructor with the other class, but I'd rather not. I also tried to add annotation processor to the other module too, but it didn't help. Is there any other way?

Please see comment from Jeff Scott Brown in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64208134/14072498
